# Initial FBSession check consistently fails

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an app in which the user may choose to login to FB. My code is based largely on the tutorials at FB, and for the most part, the app, and the FB integration works as expected. The problem I am having is that the app is not remembering from launch to launch that the user has selected to connect the app to FB. I put a check into AppDelegate.m to check for a cached FBSession:

```
   if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        // Yes, so just open the session (this won't display any UX).
        NSLog(@"The state is IS 'State created token loaded'");
        [self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO];
    } else {
        // No, display the login page.
        NSLog(@"The state is NOT 'State created token loaded'");
        [self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
    }
```

Every time I launch the app, the line "The state is NOT 'State created token loaded'" is displayed in the console. This makes me think I am not doing something right in order to make that FB login persist from launch to launch.

I could really use some advice here. What does one need to do to ensure that "FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded" is true on app launch?

Comment: Is the token stored before the app terminates? Take a look at the user default `FBAccessTokenInformationKey`.

Comment: That could be a key to my troubles. I was unaware that one has to store tokens... Is there an FB tute coving this aspect of the FB SDK?

Comment: Not that I know. You don't need to store them explicitly, but these things might slip through while you're repeatedly restarting the app while debugging. What does it say if you log `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"FBAccessTokenInformationKey"]` at startup?

Comment: It says: (null).  Which I sort of anticipated since I am not sure where to get the token to store there, nor how to use that userDefault value when launching the app to reopen the FB session. I am going to study the FBSession reference for a while at developer.fb but please do post any info you might have that would help me out. Thanks!

Comment: have you figured this out yet? I have the same issue and userDefault returns (null). Did you end up manually caching token? If so, where and how? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this code right when the app starts, then note that:

FBSession.activeSession

May not be set yet. What you want to do to check for a cached token is something like:

```
if (![self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO]) {
    [self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
}
```

The first call with the "NO" will return synchronously with a value of true if there was a a cached token. It returns no if there is no cached token. At this point you can force the login UX to happen.

Comment: This is an excellent tip. I think my problem is that I do not know how to cache the token. Any tips on how to do that? (leo suggested FBAccessTokenInformationKey might play a role).

Comment: I was under the impression that the SDK cached the token to `NSUserDefaults` by default, but take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.0/class/FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdk-reference/iossdk/3.0/class/FBSession/#FBSessionState+enum

Comment: As cbowns said, the latest SDK does the caching for you so you don't have to worry about it.